# Passport.authenticate giving false truths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

After a lot of configuration I got my local login passport method to work, except as long as there is an email and password it gives access, I think it's skipping checking for errors

```
router.post(
'/login',
  function(req,res, next){
    console.log(req.body.email)


    const validationResult = validateLoginForm(req.body);
    if (!validationResult.success) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: validationResult.message,
        errors: validationResult.errors
      });
    }

    return passport.authenticate('local', (err, token, userData) => 
          {
      if (err) {
        if (err.name === 'IncorrectCredentialsError') {
          return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
          });
        }

        return res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Could not process the form.'
        });
      }


      return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'You have successfully logged in!',
        token,
        user: userData
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

On the react side it gives a logged in state as true but a success of false, even when the right credentials are entered

```
here is the client side code

 _login(username, password){
    axios({
        method:"post",
        url: '/auth/login',
        data: {
            email: username,
            password: password
        }
    }).then(response=>{
        // .post(`/auth/login`, {
        //     username,
        //     password
        // })
        // .then(response =>{
            console.log(response)
            if (response.status ===200){
                this.setState({
                    loggedIn: true,
                    user: response.data.user
                })
             }
         })
}
```

Comment: Where is `success` being established in the client code?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the code where you define your local strategy, but at first glance, `err` will only be set if an exception occurred while authenticating the request. You should be checking whether `token` is false to ensure authentication was successful.

From the PassportJS documentation:

> If authentication failed, user will be set to false. If an exception
>   occurred, err will be set. An optional info argument will be passed,
>   containing additional details provided by the strategy's verify
>   callback.

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/#custom-callback